# How is a tooltip custom-drawn if it's always a popup?

Tags: windows, winapi, tooltip, custom-draw

The tooltip [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tooltip-styles#remarks) say that

> A tooltip control always has the WS_POPUP and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW window
> styles, regardless of whether you specify them when creating the
> control.

Meanwhile, the way to custom draw a tooltip is through [`WM_NOTIFY`/`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-tooltip), which would require a parent.

So how is custom-draw performed if the tooltip is always a popup?

Comment: Notification messages are sent to the window specified in the `TTTOOLINFO` structure when you add the tool to the tooltip.

Comment: Oh, okay, cool.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that should be posted as an answer